# Can I get the timestamp in specific time zone?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a  MySQL query that saves a comment in the database and save also the timestamp I want to save the timestamp in another time zone settings can i do it through the following query:

```
INSERT INTO tahminler 
(comment, comment_text, match_id, user_id, timestamp) 
VALUES ('$comment','$comment_text', $id, $user_id, now())
```

Comment: MySQL timestamps and datetime columns don't have a concept of a time zone.  You'd have to add an additional column to store the timezone data yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can do it with **`date_default_timezone_set()`** on PHP.

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');// Your local server time
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');// Los Angeles time
```

So replace your **`now()`** with **`date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`** after setting the timezone of your choice.

Comment: That only works if a) everyone using the system is in the same timezone or b) there's some record of the timezone for each user.

Comment: Yes right exactly. for option b), the OP may run a switch statement from this http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone provided if there's already a record.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this one

```
//default timezone
$date = new DateTime(null);
echo 'Default timezone: '.$date->getTimestamp().'<br />'."\r\n";

//America/New_York
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo 'America/New_York: '.$date->getTimestamp().'<br />'."\r\n";
```

Get the regular timestamp and add the UTC offset

```
  //America/New_York
    $date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
    echo 'America/New_York: '.($date->getTimestamp() + $date->getOffset()).'<br />'."\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your table with add column timestamp like this....

```
 ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD `lastUpdated` TIMESTAMP 
 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This adds a column called 'lastUpdated' with a default value of the current date/time. When that record is updated (lets say 5 minutes later) that timestamp will automatically update to the current time.